# Mercurial: Rename a bookmark

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I would like to change the name of a bookmark that I previously set using 
`hg bookmark xyz`
How can I rename a bookmark in mercurial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U wanna 2 read docs, namely `hg help book` in order to discover needed options

```
>hg book
 * master                    1195:b800644fcbe2

>hg book mainline -m master

>hg book
 * mainline                  1195:b800644fcbe2
```